Problem to stop a function and restart it at the same location
I have a problem with my Arduino code. I'm building a small traffic-light system which I need for my base project.
Now I have a problem, I can't get the program to stop when the button is clicked twice and to continue running in the same place when it is clicked again.
#define one_Red 3
#define one_Yellow 4
#define one_Green 5
#define two_Red 6
#define two_Yellow 7
#define two_Green 8
#define redLed 10
#define greenLed 9
#define button 2

int programRunning = false;
int brightness = 0;
int fadeAmount = 5;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long interval = 30;

unsigned long taskStartTime = 0;
const unsigned long firstTaskDuration[] = {1000, 2000, 3000, 2000, 2000};
const unsigned long resetTaskDuration[] = {1000, 2000, 3000, 2000, 2000};
int currentStep = 0;

unsigned long lastButtonPress = 0;
int buttonPressCount = 0;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(one_Red, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(one_Yellow, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(one_Green, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(two_Red, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(two_Yellow, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(two_Green, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redLed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(button, INPUT_PULLUP);

  digitalWrite(one_Red, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(one_Yellow, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(one_Green, LOW);
  digitalWrite(two_Red, LOW);
  digitalWrite(two_Yellow, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(two_Green, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(redLed, HIGH);
}

void loop()
{
  pulseRedLed();
  handleButtonPress();

  if (programRunning)
  {
    runResetTask();
  }
  else
  {
    runFirstTask();
  }
}

void handleButtonPress()
{
  if (digitalRead(button) == LOW)
  {
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    
    if (currentMillis - lastButtonPress > 800) 
    {
      lastButtonPress = currentMillis;
      buttonPressCount++;

      if (buttonPressCount == 2)
      {
        programRunning = !programRunning;
        buttonPressCount = 0; 
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    buttonPressCount = 0;
  }
}

void runFirstTask()
{
  if (digitalRead(button) == LOW && currentStep == 0)
  {
    taskStartTime = millis();
    currentStep = 1;
  }

  if (currentStep > 0)
  {
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - taskStartTime >= firstTaskDuration[currentStep - 1])
    {
      taskStartTime = currentMillis;
      switch (currentStep)
      {
      case 1:
        digitalWrite(one_Green, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(one_Yellow, LOW);
        break;
      case 2:
        digitalWrite(one_Yellow, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(one_Red, LOW);
        break;
      case 3:
        digitalWrite(two_Red, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(two_Yellow, LOW);
        break;
      case 4:
        digitalWrite(two_Yellow, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(two_Green, LOW);
        programRunning = true;
        currentStep = 0;
        return;
      }
      currentStep++;
    }
  }
}

void runResetTask()
{
  if (digitalRead(button) == LOW && currentStep == 0)
  {
    taskStartTime = millis();
    currentStep = 1;
  }

  if (currentStep > 0)
  {
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - taskStartTime >= resetTaskDuration[currentStep - 1])
    {
      taskStartTime = currentMillis;
      switch (currentStep)
      {
      case 1:
        digitalWrite(two_Green, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(two_Yellow, LOW);
        break;
      case 2:
        digitalWrite(two_Yellow, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(two_Red, LOW);
        break;
      case 3:
        digitalWrite(one_Red, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(one_Yellow, LOW);
        break;
      case 4:
        digitalWrite(one_Yellow, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(one_Green, LOW);
        programRunning = false;
        currentStep = 0;
        return;
      }
      currentStep++;
    }
  }
}

void pulseRedLed()
{
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval)
  {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    analogWrite(redLed, brightness);
    brightness += fadeAmount;

    if (brightness <= 0 || brightness >= 255)
    {
      fadeAmount = -fadeAmount;
    }
  }
}


I have tried to revise the method “handleButtonPress” with no success at the moment.

What happens currently when you click twice and then click again? The code is quite complicated (too complicated for what seems like a simple task) so the more you can say about how it currently behaves the easier it will be to follow.

@john I'm just new so my code is not so good. When I press the button twice, nothing happens, the program keeps running

You mean the programRunning is always true? You need to debug your code to find out why this is happening. Add print statements to handleButtonPress to find out exactly why programRunning never gets set to false. There are two if statements that both have to be true (at the same time) for programRunning to be set to false. So find out exactly why that is not happening.

To me it's unclear what you mean by: " I can't get the program to stop when the button is clicked twice and to continue running in the same place when it is clicked again". Stopping a program and (later) continue from the same place would (at least to me) translate into some kind of interrupt and (later) a return from interrupt. However, I see nothing in your code related to interrupt. I rather seems tthat you poll the state of a button and use that to decide which function to call.

if (currentMillis - lastButtonPress > 800) in handleButtonPress() causes the second button press to be ignored if it is less than 800 ms after the previous button press.   A human pressing a button twice can easily do two presses more quickly than that.

https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Should you really set the button press count back to 0 whenever the button is HIGH?  It can never get to two that way.  It will get set back to 0 once the button reads HIGH between presses.

I would normally expect button-events to trigger an interrupt so that an ISR (interrupt service routine) was executed. The ISR would then detect events like button-down and button-up. It could include some time based filtering to handle contact bounce.
Your code, however, seems to poll the button. And that seems to be - at least part of - the problem here.
Let's start with handleButtonPress and forget the other functions for a while. Your idea seems to be that you want to see digitalRead(button) == LOW twice. And that you use buttonPressCount to determine when that had happened.
Okay so clicking a button twice would look like:
HHHHHHHHLHHHHLHHHHHHHH  (L means LOW, H means HIGH)
        ^    ^
        1st  2nd
         click

When you see the first LOW you increment buttonPressCount, i.e. it will become 1. So far so good.
Then you see a H (HIGH) so your code takes the else path and do:
buttonPressCount = 0;

Ups... You just cleared the first click! So you can't detect the button being clicked twice!
Your current function can only do that if two consecutive executions both read the value low.
But the you have a 800ms limit also... As I assume the function would run many, many times within 800ms, it means that many, many consecutive executions must read the value low in order to avoid going into the else path and clear the counter.
So to trigger the code for "clicked twice" you need to hold the button down for a long time, i.e. more than 2x800ms.
So you need to redesign the function.
I'll suggest that you start out testing it without the present of other functions so that you have a more simple setup. For instance like:
void loop()
{
  /////////////// pulseRedLed();
  handleButtonPress();

  if (programRunning)
  {
    ///////////// runResetTask();
    turn_on_green_and_turn_off_red();
  }
  else
  {
    ///////////// runFirstTask();
    turn_off_green_and_turn_on_red();
  }
}

Once your "clicked twice" detection works, you should see the LEDs toggling between green and red when you click twice.
ohh... and consider adding checks for digitalRead(button) == HIGH. To me a click is a sequence of two events. First you detect a LOW and then you must detect a HIGH. That's a click. Also you may add an upper limit for the time between two clicks in order to consider it a double-click.
Further...
Your functions runResetTask and runFirstTask also check the button state and - if LOW - starts executing something that takes seconds!
That's a bad design. How can you know whether the first LOW is detected by e.g. runResetTask or handleButtonPress? You can't!
All handling of button state must be within a single function.

Interrupts are not generally necessary for something so slow as a human pressing a button.  Using interrupts for your buttons invites all sorts of new problems.

Interrupts are not generally necessary for something so slow as a human pressing a button.  Using interrupts for your buttons invites all sorts of new problems.

Blocking for seconds is the problem.  Don't do that.  It takes a person on the order of 500ms to press and release a button even if they are moving fast.  That should be plenty of time for a microprocessor to catch it.

BTW: just looked again at OP's code.  None of it blocks for any seconds.  None of it blocks at all.  It should be fine to poll that button.
